# Encode images into a video as they become available with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an application which takes roughly 25 seconds to process each frame of a video, and then it saves each processed frame to a dedicated directory which contains nothing but frames, and each frame is named by its position in the video, no padding.

However, each output frame is about 30MB and it would take a ludicrous ~7TB to process each frame in a 1-hour 60fps input individually and then encode them all into an MP4 at the end.

The issue is that I only have about 4TB available. So what I want is that When my processing application writes a frame to disk, FFMPEG should recognize that a new frame is available to encode, encodes it, and then deletes the original frame. This should drastically reduce the amount of needed disk storage (according to my current encoder settings), even for the longest possible video inputs I could be dealing with.

Basically I want FFMPEG to encode a video out of a series of images, but I want it to wait for each frame to become available before screaming an error code and calling it quits. I know the exact number of frames in the expected output beforehand, but I have no idea how to tell that to FFMPEG. I already have a command which I'm using, but it does not let FFMPEG wait for new input frames to become readable and it also doesn't delete frames which have been encoded.
`ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -i processed/%d.png -vf "scale=3840:2160:force_original_aspect_ratio=1" -c:v hevc_nvenc -b:v 45M -r 60 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv444p output.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem for my own specific use case by invoking ImageMagick to scale output frames by 66% of the output of the processing program. The output of ImageMagick in this case is still greater in pixel size than 4K resolution, which my video output is going to be. It makes the storage requirements a tad more bearable, however there is virtually no wiggle room beyond videos that are ~50:00 with the "limited" storage space I have available.

This is just my own unique solution to this unique problem, however everyone is encouraged to add a proper answer.

Comment: By my calculation, your original encode at 25 second per frame, would take two months to encode a single hour of 60fps video...WOW, that is unique.

Comment: @Sark 25s/frame is the best I can do with the resources I have available haha, it's not a very time-sensitive application though so this processing time is acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Just make `ffmpeg` read its input from a FIFO then it will hang around as long as it takes for each frame to be generated as long as the FIFO is being written.

The following example generates 100 frames of 640x480 video in RGB888 format and pauses for a few seconds between writing each frame to a FIFO that `ffmpeg` is reading from:

```
#!/bin/bash

SIZE="640x480"

# Make a FIFO to write to and for ffmpeg to read from
[ ! -p video ] && mkfifo video

# Genrate 100 frames of random, solid colour video of 640x480
for ((i=0;i<100;i++)) ; do
   # Generate random RGB colour
   ((R=RANDOM%255))
   ((G=RANDOM%255))
   ((B=RANDOM%255))
   >&2 echo "Sending frame $i with rgb($R,$G,$B):"
   magick -size "$SIZE" xc:"rgb($R,$G,$B)" -depth 8 rgb:-
   ((t=RANDOM%10))
   >&2 echo "Sleeping for $t seconds"
   sleep $t
done > fifo &

# Start ffmpeg reading frames from FIFO
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -video_size $SIZE -pixel_format rgb24 -framerate 1 -i fifo -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4
```

---

Note that I am writing the debug info to `stderr` with `>&2 echo` so that it is not inadvertently sent to `ffmpeg`. Note that you could equally generate the frames with Python or C/C++, you don't have to use **ImageMagick**.

---

A `bash` compound, multi-line statement amounts to the same thing if that is easier to understand:

```
{ 
  generate frame on stdout using Python/ImageMagick or other
  sleep 25
  generate frame on stdout using Python/ImageMagick or other
  sleep 25
  generate frame on stdout using Python/ImageMagick or other
  sleep 25
  generate frame on stdout using Python/ImageMagick or other
  sleep 25
} | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -video_size $SIZE -pixel_format rgb24 -framerate 1 /dev/stdin ... output.mp4
```